# This rhyming riddle is legal to the letter

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> With chase, plane, or tiger
>
> --whatever your pleasure--
>
> I have been known to fold under pressure.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it perhaps

> Paper?

With chase, plane, or tiger

--whatever your pleasure--

> Not sure about this, but paper plane makes sense. (Paper tiger is a term and there's a movie called the Paper Chase, but I'm not sure that's what the question is referring to.)

I have been known to fold under pressure.

> Fold paper.

Title

> Legal and letter are sizes of paper

Comment: You got it! Nicely done. Keep it comin'. I'll make more.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> Ace?

Chase

> chase ace a gift store(I think)

Plane

> plane ace

Tiger

> tiger ace a book

fold

> fold an ace (poker)